# Best/Correct way to create a client-server constant listener

Tags: database, sockets, websocket, listener, web-hosting

I am creating an app that involves sending and receiving settings... The desktop application is constantly sending information to a hosted MySQL database, and the Android app will query this same information. It is something similar to the whatsapp web (but in this case, I'll be using a desktop app instead of webpages).

Until this part, everything is working as I need... but, this same Android app will be used to send settings to the desktop app, and the desktop will read and change its settings according to what was just sent.

If I need to constantly query the hosted MySQL database and check if there is any kind of changes sent from the Android, I believe that I'll have a performance drop... each time a query loop is finished, I would have to query, check for any modifications and so on.

Is there a better or correct way to do this kind integration between two apps? I've read something about WebSockets, but I don't have much technical information about this, neither examples that I can use in this case.

Thank you very much for your knowledge sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some useful sites on WebSocket:

- http://websocket.org
- http://blog.kaazing.com/  [some useful blog posts]
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/
- https://goo.gl/5OaJff  [mozilla site]

You may want to consider the Observer/Observables pattern.  The MYSQL is the Observable and your desktop app and Android app are Observers (and you can add other Observers in the future).  Its a common pattern with lots of examples out there.  But you'll need a centralized WebSocket server and an Observer/Observable coordination subsystem.  You can setup a pub/sub message broker that uses WebSocket with a nice JMS, MQTT, etc, API to make your life easier.  ActiveMQ, IBM MQ Lite, Kaazing JMS Edition... lots of options.

full disclosure.  I work for Kaazing.